# TransactionScope error saving a lot of information

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactionscope

I am developing a .NET web application with C# and SQL Server as database, being newbie for both technologies. I have a problem when I attempt to save a lot of information at the same time.

My code is simple:

```
  SqlConnection cn = null;
  try
  {
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
      using (cn = Util.getConnection())
      {
        cn.Open();

        BusinessObject.saveObject1(param1, cn);
        BusinessObject.saveObject2(param2, cn);
        BusinessObject.saveObject3(param3, cn);
        BusinessObject.saveObject4(param4, cn);

        ...

        scope.Complete();

      }
    }
```

I always use the same connection object because if an error happens, I must revoke any change in my data and the same behaviour if the process is ok, is needed.

I don't mind it the process of saving takes a lot of time, in my application is perfectly normal because I have to save a lot of information.

The weirdness here is:

- When I execute this function in the same local area network of the database, it perfectly works.
- However, if I execute it from outside, such as, connected by a VPN and consequently with higher latency, I get an error with the message: *"The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements."*

I have tried to change the timeout of the database through the connection string in the web.config but it didn't resolve anything. Also, if after each executeNonQuery() statement I do a cn.Dispose(), I get an error in the next attempt to use the connection object.

Do I have to change the parameters of TransactionScope object? Is there another better way to do this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you try setting the `Timeout = 0` in your `Util.getConnection()` funciton . This will complete the job surely. By setting the `Timeout = 0` will complete every long operation job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a timeout error. The `TransactionScope` might decide to rollback the transaction in case of a timeout.

You need to increase the timeout value in the `TransactionScope` constructor. The default max. timeout is 10min.

Comment: I have changed the parameters of the TransactionScope to:

`using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions() { 
              IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
              Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
        }))`

And now it works since remote access with high latency. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move `scope.Complete();` outside the `connection` block ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the `Timeout = 0` in your `Util.getConnection()` function ? A value of 0 indicates no limit. This will complete the job surely. By setting the `Timeout = 0` will complete every long operation job.

Comment: I have included "Connection Timeout = 0" in my connection string in web.config but by this way I get again the error. Thanks.

Comment: Did you remove `scope.Complete();` outside the `connection` `using` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have tried several ways to fix the error and only works changing the timeout of the transaction scope.

Comment: Did you try setting the `TransactionScope Timeout = 0` ?